# .NET Core - FromForm doesn't pick up an IEnumerable<int>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to pass an ajax call to a REST endpoint. I have set up a DTO, and all parameters work correctly except for the two that are IEnumerbles.

DTO looks like

```
public string title{ get; set; }

public IEnumerable<int> idsToSend{ get; set; }

public IEnumerable<IFormFile> AdditionalFiles { get; set; }
```

Controller method looks like

```
[FromForm] myGreatDTO dto
```

When I send the request, in my network inspector, I can see that all 3 properties are indeed included in the request, and the content type header is set to multipart/form-data

When I breakpoint in the controller, I can see the DTO come in, but only the title (the single string) is set. Both the array of numbers and array of IFormFiles are set to "Count = 0"

I've tried googling but I can't find anything on this. Thank you for any direction.

EDIT: Here is the request from chromes network inspector as requested:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AdditionalFiles"

[object File]

------WebKitFormBoundaryun80WvPO3VUW6BU8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="idsToSend"

2,3

------WebKitFormBoundaryun80WvPO3VUW6BU8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"

a title
```

And the content type header

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryun80WvPO3VUW6BU8
```

EDIT 2: And the parsed version from chrome inspector

```
title: a title
idsToSend: 2,3
AdditionalFiles: [object File]
```

EDIT 3:
I have gotten the idsToSend to work by manually composing those values.

So rather than

```
requestObject.append('idsToSend', myvaluesarray);
```

it's a loop that puts out

```
requestObject.append('idsToSend[i]', myvaluesarray[i]);
```

So that's great.

However, doing the same with AdditionalFiles does not work. The backend reads the value as "null".

EDIT 4

Here is the front-end angular method that sends this request as requestd

```
sendRequest(dto) {
  let url = `${this._profileService.root}/document`;
  let requestObject = new FormData();
  //fill in the base keys
  requestObject.append('Title', dto.Title);

  for (let i = 0; i < dto.ids.length; i++) {
    requestObject.append(`idsToSend[${i}]`, dto.ids[i].toString());
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < dto.AdditionalFiles.length; j++) {
    requestObject.append(`AdditionalFiles[${j}]`, dto.AdditionalFiles[j]);
  }

  return this._http.post(url, requestObject).catch(this.errorHandler);
}
```

Comment: You'll need to add how the request looks like

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have added the formdata from my inspector above.

Comment: Wich version of .NET Core SDK are you working with?

Comment: It's better to show us the complete code. How you construct the `requestObject` and send the request?

Comment: @itminus I have added the angular service that fires this off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`IEnumerable<IFormFile>`** is different from simple fields. Every element within this collection is designed to has its own file name. There's no need to construct a field name like `AdditionalFiles[]`.

Use `AdditionalFiles` as the field names directly (instead of `AdditionalFiles[]`), as the type itself already indicates that's a collection type.

```
sendRequest(dto) {
  let url = `${this._profileService.root}/document`;
  let requestObject = new FormData();
  //fill in the base keys
  requestObject.append('Title', dto.Title);

  for (let i = 0; i  < dto.ids.length; i++) {
    requestObject.append(`idsToSend[${i}]`, dto.ids[i].toString());
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < dto.AdditionalFiles.length; j++) {
    requestObject.append(`AdditionalFiles[${j}]`, dto.AdditionalFiles[j]);
    requestObject.append(`additionalFiles`, dto.AdditionalFiles[j]);
  }

  return this._http.post(url, requestObject).catch(this.errorHandler);
}
```